# Changing ac 15 amp breaker to 15 regular breaker

Tags: hvac, receptacle

I have a ac outlet hooked up to a large (takes up two spaces on board) 15 amp breaker . I want to replace the outlet to a regular two outlet receptacle , no longer need the AC . Do I replace the large 15 amp breaker for the smaller 15 amp breaker?

Comment: Presumably "AC" here means Air Conditioner, not Alternating Current, and the goal is to repurpose the outlet box from 240V to 120V.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to change out the double pole breaker to a single pole unless you need the breaker space for something else. I'd remove one of the wires from the breaker and cap it with a wire nut. Do the same to the other end in the outlet junction box. If you have a white wire in the junction blox, you can use it with the wire from the breaker for your outlet. If you don't have a white wire, you can't repurpose one of the other wires for the neutral.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Most likely, your A/C circuit is #3 here (possibly #4). Since it was a 240V air conditioner, it doesn't actually use neutral for anything, so neutral is not there.

However, to save money on wire, it was most likely wired with "/2+ground" cable (black-white-bare).   This cable has a white wire in it, yet a second hot wire is needed, so typically the white wire is used as the second hot (which can be confusing).  Recent rules require that when a white is used that way, it must be marked with black or red tape etc.  But most likely, yours is not marked.

Converting the breaker is *super, super easy*.  Simply remove the white wire from the breaker, and place it on the panel's neutral bar. (where all the other white wires congregate).  If you can't reach, a wire nut and short pigtail extension can be used.  Most better hardware stores will sell you 1 foot of white #12 THHN wire for a quarter, and a wire nut for another dime.  You don't need to do anything else to the breaker, and you don't need to buy 2 new breakers*.

It is absolutely vital that you change the socket to match the new voltage! Never run a socket on the wrong voltage - you'll start a fire.  All these sockets in the above photo are *right next to each other* on the hardware store's shelves. The ones on the right aren't sold by the billion, and so don't benefit from the economies of scale that can make #1 as little as a dollar.  Some 240V sockets have only a single socket; that's fine, they are interchangeable with any of these.

Stay with the same amps ("15A" or "20A").  If your old socket was #3, use #1.   If it was #4, use #2.

---

---

---

---

* Why would you need 2 breakers?  *You can't leave an empty gaping hole in the panel*.  You need to fill it with *something*. Filler plates are flimsy and don't last, and cost nearly as much as a breaker, and breakers are useful, so I recommend a breaker **as** a filler plate if you're doing that, which I recommend you don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can or just remove one wire from the other half of the breaker.

Can also make it into a multi wire branch circuit, two circuits using the same neutral.

The only problem might be if the AC was 240v only(two hots and ground) and did not have neutral.  In this case there usually is a white wire on the breaker instead of a red wire.

Comment: The MWBC won't work unless the cable is /3, which is unlikely for an A/C.